# Open File Explorer On Button Click in React

Tags: reactjs, node.js, electron, craco

I am trying to make it so that when clicking a button, the file explorer will open to a specific directory path. I have the project and files I want to access all in the same directory. Here's a link to my site: https://nfsdownload.teleporthq.app/

If I use:

```
require('child_process').exec('start "" "c:\\test"');
```

I get an error that webpack_require_ exec isn't a function.

If I use:

```
function openFile(path) {
    window.open(path, "_blank");
  }

<button type="button" className="nfs-slideshow-button BIG button">
                <span className="nfs-slideshow-text02 Button1" onclick={ openFile("C:\\NeedForSpeed\\nfsUnderground")}>
                  <span className="nfs-slideshow-text03">PLAY</span>
                  <br></br>
```

I get "not allowed to load local resource" and "server responded with a status of 404" due to browser security settings. Would this go away if I compiled my project into an exe somehow?

Using electron:

```
const {shell} = require('electron') // deconstructing assignment

shell.showItemInFolder('filepath') // Show the given file in a file manager. 
shell.openPath('folderpath') // Open the file in the default

<button type="button" className="nfs-slideshow-button BIG button">
                <span className="nfs-slideshow-text02 Button1" onClick={ shell.openPath('C:/NeedForSpeed/nfsUnderground')}>
                  <span className="nfs-slideshow-text03">PLAY</span>
                  <br></br>
                </span>
```

I get:

```
ERROR in ./node_modules/electron/index.js 1:11-24
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'C:\NeedForSpeed\ReactApp\node_modules\electron'
ERROR in ./node_modules/electron/index.js 2:13-28
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'path' in 'C:\NeedForSpeed\ReactApp\node_modules\electron'

BREAKING CHANGE: webpack < 5 used to include polyfills for node.js core modules by default.
This is no longer the case. Verify if you need this module and configure a polyfill for it.

If you want to include a polyfill, you need to:
    - add a fallback 'resolve.fallback: { "path": require.resolve("path-browserify") }'
    - install 'path-browserify'
If you don't want to include a polyfill, you can use an empty module like this:
    resolve.fallback: { "path": false }
```

I am unsure of how to fix this due to the project being made with craco, so I don't have the typical webpack.config.js file. Here is my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "need-for-speed-download",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@craco/craco": "^7.0.0-alpha.0",
    "electron": "^28.0.0",
    "prop-types": "15.7.2",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "craco start",
    "build": "craco build",
    "test": "craco test --env=jsdom",
    "eject": "craco eject"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "18.x"
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1"
  }
}
```

Here's my craco.config.js:

```
module.exports = {
  reactScriptsVersion: "react-scripts",
  style: {
    css: {
      loaderOptions: () => {
        return {
          url: false,
        };
      },
    },
  },
};
```

And here is the js file I am trying to add the file opener to:

```
import React from 'react'

import PropTypes from 'prop-types'

import './nfs-slideshow.css'

const NfsSlideshow = (props) => {
  const {shell} = require('electron')
  return (
    <div className="nfs-slideshow-container">
      <div
        data-thq="slider"
        data-navigation="true"
        data-pagination="true"
        className="nfs-slideshow-slider swiper"
      >
        <div data-thq="slider-wrapper" className="swiper-wrapper">
          <div
            data-thq="slider-slide"
            className="nfs-slideshow-nfs1994 swiper-slide"
          >
            <div className="nfs-slideshow-container01">
              <img
                alt="https://assets-prd.ignimgs.com/2022/08/31/needforspeed1-1661936473788.jpg?width=300&amp;crop=1%3A1%2Csmart&amp;auto=webp"
                src="https://hips.hearstapps.com/hmg-prod/images/roa110120fea-nfs-008-1604351948.jpg?resize=980:*"
                className="nfs-slideshow-image"
              />
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text">{props.nfs1994_heading}</h1>
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text01">{props.nfs1994_year}</h1>
              <button type="button" className="nfs-slideshow-button BIG button">
                <span className="nfs-slideshow-text02 Button1" onClick={ shell.openPath('C:/NeedForSpeed/nfsUnderground')}>
                  <span className="nfs-slideshow-text03">PLAY</span>
                  <br></br>
                </span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div
            data-thq="slider-slide"
            className="nfs-slideshow-nfs-hot-pursuit3 swiper-slide"
          >
            <div className="nfs-slideshow-container02">
              <img
                alt="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/nfs/images/2/28/NFSIIIHP_Boxart.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20191028081942&amp;path-prefix=en"
                src="https://assets-prd.ignimgs.com/2022/05/13/nfs3hp-1652477699912.jpg"
                className="nfs-slideshow-image01"
              />
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text05">
                {props.nfs3HotPursuit_nfs}
              </h1>
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text06">
                {props.nfs3HotPursuit_year}
              </h1>
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text07">
                {props.nfs3HotPursuit_title}
              </h1>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="nfs-slideshow-button01 BIG button"
              >
                <span className="nfs-slideshow-text08 Button1">
                  <span className="nfs-slideshow-text09">PLAY</span>
                  <br></br>
                </span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div
            data-thq="slider-slide"
            className="nfs-slideshow-nfs-high-stakes swiper-slide"
          >
            <div className="nfs-slideshow-container03">
              <img
                alt="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/nfs/images/9/90/NFSHS_Boxart.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20191027140115&amp;path-prefix=en"
                src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/e/e2/NFS_High_Stakes_box.jpg"
                className="nfs-slideshow-image02"
              />
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text11">
                {props.nfsHighStakes_nfs}
              </h1>
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text12">
                {props.nfsHighStakes_year}
              </h1>
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text13">
                {props.nfsHighStakes_title}
              </h1>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="nfs-slideshow-button02 BIG button"
              >
                <span className="nfs-slideshow-text14 Button1">
                  <span className="nfs-slideshow-text15">PLAY</span>
                  <br></br>
                </span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div
            data-thq="slider-slide"
            className="nfs-slideshow-nfs-porche-unleashed swiper-slide"
          >
            <div className="nfs-slideshow-container04">
              <img
                alt="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/nfs/images/d/d8/NFSPUBoxArt.png/revision/latest?cb=20220304213938&amp;path-prefix=en"
                src="https://assets-prd.ignimgs.com/2022/03/25/nfsporsche-1648251035942.jpg"
                className="nfs-slideshow-image03"
              />
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text17">{props.nfsPorche_nfs}</h1>
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text18">{props.nfsPorche_year}</h1>
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text19">{props.nfsPorche_title}</h1>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="nfs-slideshow-button03 BIG button"
              >
                <span className="nfs-slideshow-text20 Button1">
                  <span className="nfs-slideshow-text21">PLAY</span>
                  <br></br>
                </span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div
            data-thq="slider-slide"
            className="nfs-slideshow-nfs-hot-pursuit2 swiper-slide"
          >
            <div className="nfs-slideshow-container05">
              <img
                alt="https://assets-prd.ignimgs.com/2022/01/21/need-for-speed-hot-pursuit-2-ps2-button-1642795801243.jpg"
                src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/ru/9/99/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B8%D0%B3%D1%80%D1%8B_Need_for_Speed_Hot_Pursuit_2.jpg"
                className="nfs-slideshow-image04"
              />
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text23">
                {props.nfsHotPursuit2_nfs}
              </h1>
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text24">
                {props.nfsHotPursuit2_year}
              </h1>
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text25">
                {props.nfsHotPursuit2_title}
              </h1>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="nfs-slideshow-button04 BIG button"
              >
                <span className="nfs-slideshow-text26 Button1">
                  <span className="nfs-slideshow-text27">PLAY</span>
                  <br></br>
                </span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div
            data-thq="slider-slide"
            className="nfs-slideshow-nfs-underground swiper-slide"
          >
            <div className="nfs-slideshow-container06">
              <img
                alt="https://www.giantbomb.com/a/uploads/scale_medium/8/87790/1897548-box_nfsug.png"
                src="https://assets-prd.ignimgs.com/2022/03/25/nfsundergroundgba-1648241328415.jpg"
                className="nfs-slideshow-image05"
              />
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text29">{props.nfsUng_nfs}</h1>
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text30">{props.nfsUng_year}</h1>
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text31">{props.nfsUng_title}</h1>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="nfs-slideshow-button05 BIG button"
              >
                <span className="nfs-slideshow-text32 Button1">
                  <span className="nfs-slideshow-text33">PLAY</span>
                  <br></br>
                </span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div
            data-thq="slider-slide"
            className="nfs-slideshow-nfs-underground2 swiper-slide"
          >
            <div className="nfs-slideshow-container07">
              <img
                alt="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BNTZlZTZiZjktYWJlZi00NTU1LWJiMmQtOTEzNmFlZWE3NjNlXkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTgyNTA4MjM@._V1_FMjpg_UX1000_.jpg"
                src="https://assets-prd.ignimgs.com/2022/01/21/need-for-speed-underground-2-button-crop-1642797115202.jpg"
                className="nfs-slideshow-image06"
              />
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text35">{props.nfsUng2_nfs}</h1>
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text36">{props.nfsUng2_year}</h1>
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text37">{props.nfsUng2_title}</h1>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="nfs-slideshow-button06 BIG button"
              >
                <span className="nfs-slideshow-text38 Button1">
                  <span className="nfs-slideshow-text39">PLAY</span>
                  <br></br>
                </span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div
            data-thq="slider-slide"
            className="nfs-slideshow-nfs-most-wanted swiper-slide"
          >
            <div className="nfs-slideshow-container08">
              <img
                alt="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/nfs/images/5/5f/NFSMW_BlackEdition_Boxart.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20200606133400&amp;path-prefix=en"
                src="https://e1.pxfuel.com/desktop-wallpaper/683/461/desktop-wallpaper-need-for-speed-most-wanted-black-edition.jpg"
                className="nfs-slideshow-image07"
              />
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text41">{props.nfsMostWant_nfs}</h1>
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text42">{props.nfsMostWant_year}</h1>
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text43">
                {props.nfsMostWant_title}
              </h1>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="nfs-slideshow-button07 BIG button"
              >
                <span className="nfs-slideshow-text44 Button1">
                  <span className="nfs-slideshow-text45">PLAY</span>
                  <br></br>
                </span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div
            data-thq="slider-slide"
            className="nfs-slideshow-nfs-carbon swiper-slide"
          >
            <div className="nfs-slideshow-container09">
              <img
                alt="https://images.igdb.com/igdb/image/upload/t_cover_big_2x/co209k.jpg"
                src="https://images.stopgame.ru/games/logos/8065/need_for_speed_carbon-square_1.jpg"
                className="nfs-slideshow-image08"
              />
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text47">{props.nfsCarbon_nfs}</h1>
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text48">{props.nfsCarbon_year}</h1>
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text49">{props.nfsCarbon_title}</h1>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="nfs-slideshow-button08 BIG button"
              >
                <span className="nfs-slideshow-text50 Button1">
                  <span className="nfs-slideshow-text51">PLAY</span>
                  <br></br>
                </span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div
            data-thq="slider-slide"
            className="nfs-slideshow-nfs-prostreet swiper-slide"
          >
            <div className="nfs-slideshow-container10">
              <img
                alt="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/en/1/16/NFS_ProStreet_cover.png"
                src="https://cdn2.steamgriddb.com/file/sgdb-cdn/grid/8bb604aef2c0b402c5006bba0e536e3e.png"
                className="nfs-slideshow-image09"
              />
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text53">{props.nfsProstreet_nfs}</h1>
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text54">
                {props.nfsProstreet_year}
              </h1>
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text55">
                {props.nfsProstreet_title}
              </h1>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="nfs-slideshow-button09 BIG button"
              >
                <span className="nfs-slideshow-text56 Button1">
                  <span className="nfs-slideshow-text57">PLAY</span>
                  <br></br>
                </span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div
            data-thq="slider-slide"
            className="nfs-slideshow-nfs-undercover swiper-slide"
          >
            <div className="nfs-slideshow-container11">
              <img
                alt="https://downloadwap.com/thumbs4/games/preview/2020d/img/368748_need_for_speed_under_1.jpg"
                src="https://assets-prd.ignimgs.com/2022/03/25/nfsundercover-1648241420268.jpg"
                className="nfs-slideshow-image10"
              />
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text59">{props.nfsUnder_nfs}</h1>
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text60">{props.nfsUnder_year}</h1>
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text61">{props.nfsUnder_title}</h1>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="nfs-slideshow-button10 BIG button"
              >
                <span className="nfs-slideshow-text62 Button1">
                  <span className="nfs-slideshow-text63">PLAY</span>
                  <br></br>
                </span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div
            data-thq="slider-slide"
            className="nfs-slideshow-nfs-shift swiper-slide"
          >
            <div className="nfs-slideshow-container12">
              <img
                alt="https://assets-prd.ignimgs.com/2022/08/31/nfsshiftpsp-1661952573028.jpg"
                src="https://static.wikia.nocookie.net/nfs/images/3/3d/NFSS_Boxart.jpg/revision/latest?cb=20180301170009&amp;path-prefix=en"
                className="nfs-slideshow-image11"
              />
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text65">{props.nfsShift_nfs}</h1>
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text66">{props.nfsShift_year}</h1>
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text67">{props.nfsShift_title}</h1>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="nfs-slideshow-button11 BIG button"
              >
                <span className="nfs-slideshow-text68 Button1">
                  <span className="nfs-slideshow-text69">PLAY</span>
                  <br></br>
                </span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div
            data-thq="slider-slide"
            className="nfs-slideshow-nfs-shift2-unleashed swiper-slide"
          >
            <div className="nfs-slideshow-container13">
              <img
                alt="https://www.gamingdragons.com/images/game_img/nfss2u.jpg"
                src="https://assets-prd.ignimgs.com/2022/04/04/shift2unleashed-1649108537152.jpg"
                className="nfs-slideshow-image12"
              />
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text71">{props.nfsShift2_nfs}</h1>
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text72">{props.nfsShift2_year}</h1>
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text73">{props.nfsShift2_title}</h1>
            </div>
            <button type="button" className="nfs-slideshow-button12 BIG button">
              <span className="nfs-slideshow-text74 Button1">
                <span className="nfs-slideshow-text75">PLAY</span>
                <br></br>
              </span>
            </button>
          </div>
          <div
            data-thq="slider-slide"
            className="nfs-slideshow-nfs-the-run swiper-slide"
          >
            <div className="nfs-slideshow-container14">
              <img
                alt="https://m.media-amazon.com/images/M/MV5BZjBlMGFlYTMtZTY0NS00YTgwLWFjNjMtODUwNWE5NDBiNzk1XkEyXkFqcGdeQXVyNTgyNTA4MjM@._V1_.jpg"
                src="https://www.giantbomb.com/a/uploads/original/9/93770/2392938-3.jpg"
                className="nfs-slideshow-image13"
              />
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text77">{props.nfsRun_nfs}</h1>
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text78">{props.nfsRun_year}</h1>
              <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text79">{props.nfsRun_title}</h1>
              <button
                type="button"
                className="nfs-slideshow-button13 BIG button"
              >
                <span className="nfs-slideshow-text80 Button1">
                  <span className="nfs-slideshow-text81">PLAY</span>
                  <br></br>
                </span>
              </button>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div
          data-thq="slider-pagination"
          className="nfs-slideshow-slider-pagination swiper-pagination swiper-pagination-bullets swiper-pagination-horizontal"
        >
          <div
            data-thq="slider-pagination-bullet"
            className="swiper-pagination-bullet swiper-pagination-bullet-active"
          ></div>
        </div>
        <div
          data-thq="slider-button-prev"
          className="nfs-slideshow-slider-button-prev swiper-button-prev"
        ></div>
        <div
          data-thq="slider-button-next"
          className="nfs-slideshow-slider-button-next swiper-button-next"
        ></div>
      </div>
      <div className="nfs-slideshow-container15">
        <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text83">
          if you have any issues running any games,
        </h1>
        <a
          href="https://path/to/drivers"
          target="_blank"
          rel="noreferrer noopener"
          className="nfs-slideshow-link"
        >
          <h1 className="nfs-slideshow-text84">download these drivers</h1>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  )
}

NfsSlideshow.defaultProps = {
  nfsUnder_nfs: 'Need for Speed',
  nfsHighStakes_title: 'High Stakes',
  nfsHotPursuit2_year: '2002',
  nfsUng2_year: '2004',
  nfsShift_year: '2009',
  nfsHighStakes_nfs: 'Need for Speed',
  nfsPorche_year: '2000',
  nfsUng2_title: 'Underground 2',
  nfsShift2_year: '2011',
  nfsCarbon_year: '2006',
  nfs3HotPursuit_year: '1998',
  nfsPorche_title: 'Porche Unleashed',
  nfsMostWant_nfs: 'Need for Speed',
  nfsProstreet_year: '2007',
  nfsUng_nfs: 'Need for Speed',
  nfsUng_title: 'Underground',
  nfsCarbon_nfs: 'Need for Speed',
  nfsUnder_title: 'Undercover',
  nfsProstreet_title: 'Prostreet',
  nfsProstreet_nfs: 'Need for Speed',
  nfsHotPursuit2_title: 'Hot Pursuit 2',
  nfsHighStakes_year: '1999',
  nfsRun_nfs: 'Need For Speed',
  heading2: 'Heading',
  nfsUnder_year: '2008',
  nfs1994_year: '1994',
  nfs3HotPursuit_title: 'Hot Pursuit',
  nfsShift2_nfs: 'Need For Speed',
  nfsHotPursuit2_nfs: 'Need for Speed',
  heading: 'Heading',
  nfsShift_nfs: 'Need for Speed',
  nfsRun_title: 'The Run',
  nfsMostWant_year: '2005',
  nfsMostWant_title: 'Most Wanted',
  nfs3HotPursuit_nfs: 'NEED FOR SPEED III',
  nfs1994_heading: 'THE NEED FOR SPEED',
  nfsCarbon_title: 'Carbon',
  nfsShift_title: 'Shift',
  nfsShift2_title: 'Shift 2: Unleashed',
  nfsUng2_nfs: 'Need for Speed',
  nfsPorche_nfs: 'Need for Speed',
  nfsUng_year: '2003',
  nfsRun_year: '2011',
}

NfsSlideshow.propTypes = {
  nfsUnder_nfs: PropTypes.string,
  nfsHighStakes_title: PropTypes.string,
  nfsHotPursuit2_year: PropTypes.string,
  nfsUng2_year: PropTypes.string,
  nfsShift_year: PropTypes.string,
  nfsHighStakes_nfs: PropTypes.string,
  nfsPorche_year: PropTypes.string,
  nfsUng2_title: PropTypes.string,
  nfsShift2_year: PropTypes.string,
  nfsCarbon_year: PropTypes.string,
  nfs3HotPursuit_year: PropTypes.string,
  nfsPorche_title: PropTypes.string,
  nfsMostWant_nfs: PropTypes.string,
  nfsProstreet_year: PropTypes.string,
  nfsUng_nfs: PropTypes.string,
  nfsUng_title: PropTypes.string,
  nfsCarbon_nfs: PropTypes.string,
  nfsUnder_title: PropTypes.string,
  nfsProstreet_title: PropTypes.string,
  nfsProstreet_nfs: PropTypes.string,
  nfsHotPursuit2_title: PropTypes.string,
  nfsHighStakes_year: PropTypes.string,
  nfsRun_nfs: PropTypes.string,
  heading2: PropTypes.string,
  nfsUnder_year: PropTypes.string,
  nfs1994_year: PropTypes.string,
  nfs3HotPursuit_title: PropTypes.string,
  nfsShift2_nfs: PropTypes.string,
  nfsHotPursuit2_nfs: PropTypes.string,
  heading: PropTypes.string,
  nfsShift_nfs: PropTypes.string,
  nfsRun_title: PropTypes.string,
  nfsMostWant_year: PropTypes.string,
  nfsMostWant_title: PropTypes.string,
  nfs3HotPursuit_nfs: PropTypes.string,
  nfs1994_heading: PropTypes.string,
  nfsCarbon_title: PropTypes.string,
  nfsShift_title: PropTypes.string,
  nfsShift2_title: PropTypes.string,
  nfsUng2_nfs: PropTypes.string,
  nfsPorche_nfs: PropTypes.string,
  nfsUng_year: PropTypes.string,
  nfsRun_year: PropTypes.string,
}

export default NfsSlideshow
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, it's important to know that for [security](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security) reasons, various security features are activated by default on your [`BrowserWindow`](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/browser-window), and unless you are *sure* security doesn't apply on your app, **you should not disable them**. This is the default recommended configuration:

```js
new BrowserWindow({
  webPreferences: {
    contextIsolation: true,
    nodeIntegration: false,
    webSecurity: true,
    sandbox: true
  }
});
```

When configured like this, you will get `require` error when trying to `require`/`import` something you're not allowed to.

In the other hand, when you get this error:

```bash
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in 'xxx'
```

It means you're trying to use Electron and/or Node.js APIs into your renderer (i.e. your React code), which – apart from being [unsecure](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/security#2-do-not-enable-nodejs-integration-for-remote-content) – your bundler ([webpack](https://webpack.js.org/)) is not configured for.

If you need to call Node.js/Electron stuff from your React code without disabling security, you need to use a [preload](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/tutorial-preload) file and [IPC](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/ipc). In addition, make sure to read about [sandboxing](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/tutorial/sandbox).

Finally, for the `not allowed to load local resource` error, this is because of `webSecurity`. It's not clear what you mean by "open file explorer", but maybe what you want is to use a [dialog](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/dialog). Otherwise, if using IPC doesn't solve the issue, you may have to use a custom [protocol](https://www.electronjs.org/docs/latest/api/protocol/).